# Express HTTP Only Cookie issues

Tags: javascript, api, express, http, cookies

Here is the request being made to the `api.website.api` server from `website.app`.

`website.app` has a http secure cookie

[image]

I'm assuming the http cookie is being sent along in the request?

```
axios.get('api.website.app/route',{withCredentials: true}).then(res => {
// some code
})
```

In an auth middleware function, I call req.cookies.access_token but it's not being verified on the request. It seems the server isn't getting the cookie from the http request. I'm trying to get the server to verify the token but it's not doing so.
[image]

This is the middleware function I am using

[image]

The route in express using the auth middleware.

Comment: If you confirmed and certain that the cookie is in the request, then the issue is server-side. So that's the stuff you need to share in your question

Comment: @Evert Can i confirm that the cookie is being sent based on the image above? Chrome tools - networks - headers i can see the cookie in request headers and in the cookie tab

Comment: Can you `console.log(req.cookies)`. Does something show up there?

Comment: @Evert Only an empty object shows. I also tested with `httpOnly` and `secure` to false and `console.log(req.cookies) in production and still an empty object

Comment: If you use the cookie-parser middleware, could the cookies live on `req.signedCookies` ?

Comment: @Evert `req.signedCookies shows another empty object. Here's the request object console.logged https://pastebin.com/sXCpGPdw

Comment: I am a little stumped too then =(

Comment: @Evert no problem, reading the express docs `req.cookies` defaults to an object when the request contains no cookies.. I'm guessing the client isn't actually sending the cookie to the server